# How to edit CSL code to group references cited at the same location in bibliography (i.e. 1a-c instead of 1-3)

Tags: mendeley, csl

I'm using Mendeley as a reference manager and Word plug-in and I need to change how it lists references in the bibliography that are cited at the same location in the text.

I've tried using the visual editing tool (https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/) but it's not going well. Thank you for your time!

Instead of individual references in the bibliography (i.e. reference (1), (2), and (3)) I want it to group anything cited at the some position in the text so I can simply cite "1" in-text and have the bibliography formatted as "(1)a,b,c".

Comment: There are thousand of citation styles out there. I'm sure one of them does already what you need. I'd ask around first before considering writing your own style. In both case Mendeley can only consume citation style, so you'd have to point it to the style that you need. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid CSL (and thus Mendeley) [doesn't support](https://citationstyles.org/authors/#/csl-limitations) these sort of "composite" styles, which is why even the styles for journals that allow this (like Angewandte Chemie) don't implement it.